# Sencha CMD stable version

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

When I got into Sencha Touch world I started using **Sencha CMD 5** along with **Sencha Touch 2.3.1**.
I However, I started to find the 5 versions not stable, they are running into many problems.

I am about to release my App and I am in need for a stable version in all aspects (Production, Native and Testing).

Would it be a good idea to use the latest **CMD 4.0.4.84**? Is it considered **stable**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sencha CMD 5 was built for Ext JS 5.

It is recommend to use Sencha Cmd 4.0.4.84 for Touch 2.3 projects.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to add "app watch" for CMD 4?